# Variation of Action and Border Terms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, integration, variational-principle, action

I need to compute the following  very general (piece of) variation:

\begin{equation}
\int d^4x \delta (\sqrt{-g} R ) f  
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $R$ is Ricci scalar and $f$ a generic scalar function .

---

It is well-known from classical GR that

\begin{equation}
\int d^4x  \delta (\sqrt{-g} R ) = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} G_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} + \sqrt{-g}  \nabla_{\sigma} [ g_{\mu \nu} \nabla^{\sigma } \delta g^{\mu\nu} - \nabla_{\lambda} \delta g^{\sigma \lambda}] . \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Using this, my book states that  variation (1) is :

\begin{multline}
\int d^4x \delta (\sqrt{-g} R ) f  = \int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} (G_{\mu\nu}+g_{\mu\nu}\Box-\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu} ) f \delta g ^{\mu\nu} + \\
\sqrt{-g} \nabla_{\sigma} \left[ (g_{\mu\nu} \nabla^{\sigma} \delta g^{\mu\nu} - \nabla_{\lambda}\delta g^{\sigma\lambda})f - (g^{\lambda \sigma} g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} - \delta g^{\lambda\sigma })\nabla_{\lambda} f  \right]. 
 \end{multline}

It is clear that in the second and third terms of the first line one has integrated by parts two times, ok. **But what about all the terms in the second line?** Where do they come from ?

Comment: When you integrate by parts, you get extra total derivative terms. Presumably the terms in the second line are those.

Comment: @Prahar sure but how

Comment: Maybe, one has to transform the boundary terms (on $\partial \Omega$) in integrals on full domain $\Omega$ by using Stokes theorem...

Comment: You have to use $a ( \nabla_\mu b ) = \nabla_\mu ( a b ) - ( \nabla_\mu a ) b $. Whenever you see a derivative acting on $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ you transfer that derivative on to other terms using this. You'll then be left over with one set of terms without any derivative acting on $\delta g$ and another set of terms that are total derivatives.